# Sub Grouping in Logi XML (Logi Report)

Tags: sql, report

I am looking for sub-grouping feature like the following image shows. [image]

I have searched a lot, but unable to find a way of how to do this in Logi reports. I am generating this report using a SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your question, it sounds like:

- you have a relational database that you are accessing via SQL
- you would like to group the data (from what I can tell of your picture you would like to group the data by age class) and provide summary information for each group

If I did understand your question, I would put something like the following inside my report definition file (update your IDs and the query to pull appropriately, the below are simply example IDs) :

```
<Body>
    <DataTable ID="myDataTable">
        <DataLayer Type="SQL" Source="SELECT * FROM MYTABLE" ConnectionID="my_database_connection">
            <SqlParameters>
                <SqlParameter ID="userParameter1" />
            </SqlParameters>
            <GroupFilter ID="myGroupFilter" GroupColumn="column_from_query_to_group_by" KeepGroupedRows="">
                <GroupAggregateColumn ID="groupCalculation1" AggregateColumn="column_from_query_to_sum_by" AggregateFunction="Sum" />
                <GroupAggregateColumn ID="groupCalculation2" AggregateColumn="column_from_query_to_avg" AggregateFunction="Average" />
            </GroupFilter>
        </DataLayer>
        <GroupHeaderRow GroupFilterID="myGroupFilter">
            <Column ID="group_header_col1">
                <Label Caption="@Data.groupCalculation1~" />
            </Column>
        </GroupHeaderRow>
        <GroupSummaryRow GroupFilterID="myGroupFilter">
            <Column ID="group_sum_col1">
                <Label Caption="@Data.groupCalculation2~" />
            </Column>       
        </GroupSummaryRow>
    </DataTable>
</Body>
```

For data grouping like the above you will probably want to use the Group Filter, Group Header Row and Group Summary Row elements, which you can learn more about here:

http://devnet.logianalytics.com/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=2150&dnProd=2
http://devnet.logianalytics.com/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=2050&dnProd=2

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Currently logi does not support this feature